# Non-linear differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\dfrac{1}{y}\left (\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2-\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0,\quad y(0)=0, y(1)=1.$ What is $y(2)$? A rearrangement gives $\left (\dfrac{1}{y'}\right )'+\dfrac{1}{y'}=y$.  I do not know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $yy''+(y')^2-yy'=0$ and $z:=y^2$ you get

$$z''-z'=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

You made a little mistake. It should be
$$\left (\dfrac{1}{y'}\right )'+\dfrac{1}{y'}=\frac 1y$$

**Another approach**
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\dfrac{1}{y}\left (\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2-\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0,\quad y(0)=0, y(1)=1.$$
$$y''+\dfrac{1}{y}(y')^2=y'$$
Multiply by $y (y \neq 0)$
$$yy''+(y')^2=y'y$$
This equation is separable
$$(y'y)'=y'y$$
Simply integrate
$$\int \frac { d(y'y)}{y'y}=\int dx$$
$$\ln(y'y)=x+K \implies y'y=Ke^x$$
$$\frac 12(y^2)'=Ke^x \implies (y^2)'=Ce^x$$
$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt {c_1e^x+c_2}$$
$$\boxed {y(x)=k_1\sqrt {e^x+k_2}}$$
Apply the initial condition to find $k_1,k_2$